# What to do if you visit Freelancing SE everyday but there are no questions to answer?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Freelancing SE is now just 5 weeks old. It's normal for things to slow down slightly after the initial excitement of the private and public beta wear off. We're still in a critical period where what we do now will help shape the community as more content is created.

So, I know there are folks visiting here everyday looking for questions to answer, but in cases where it's been a day or two since anyone has posted a question, it may *appear* that there isn't much to do.

Basically, we need to take the energy and enthusiasm that we'd normally put into answering questions and redirect that to other activities. What are some things that we can do to help the site grow and succeed?

Answer (score 4):

## Content is King - Edit and Improve Posts

We don't have many people with full edit permissions yet, but you can always suggest an edit on a post to improve it. Focus on the question titles. Are they easily searchable on Google? Does it help describe what the question is about? If not, suggested edits that just focus on the title are valid, and we should approve those.

For suggested edits made to the post body and question body, be sure to fix as many problems as you see. If you see a typo and want to fix it, that's fine, but be sure to fix any other problems that are evident in the post. Substantial suggested edits ensure that only posts are bumped to the top of the active page that are worth taking up space and having the community re-read them.

Edits should ideally make the site look more attractive to anyone finding the site from search engines. If the content is high quality and attractive, we'll possibly pick up more people.

## Suggest Edits to Tag Wikis

Many tags don't have a description of what types of questions they should be used for.  If you see a tag that doesn't have a description, consider suggesting an edit.

Remember, the goal of the excerpt isn't to define the term, it's to describe what types of questions should have the tag. The tag wiki body should go into more detail, including defining applicable terms.  Also, this is a good time to include good examples of questions that have that tag.

## Vote on posts

Reputation is the currency that will give the core community the power to help moderate it. If you see a good question or a good answer, up vote it! As more people gain reputation, more people will be able to make full edits without needing approval.

## Join the Chat Room

The healthiest Stack Exchange communities have a [core group of users in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8874/freelancing). Even though we're not that large and there won't be many active chats going on, drop in occasionally and say "Hi" or contribute to a discussion. Even if the last three posts in a discussion were all spread out over the course of several hours, post something anyway. Chat doesn't have to be completely real-time at first, but we do need to use it!

I've also activated the RSS Feed for new questions so that a link to them is dropped in chat every time a new question is posted on the main Q&A site. Feel free to comment on how the question could be improved, answered, or even closed if it isn't a good fit for the site. Also, use that as an opportunity to up vote the content if it's good.

## Focus on Social Media/Blogging

If you have a blog, Twitter, Facebook, or LinkedIn account, go through the best questions on our site and blog about them or share them with your followers. This will help bring more like-minded people into the community and help us create more attractive content.

## Ask a Question

Of course, if you come up with an interesting Freelancing challenge, post a question on the site. Be sure to include a description of the problem and details.

One word of caution, try to avoid questions that aren't about a real problem you're facing. These tend to look very generic and overly broad. Content such as that may not be helpful to our site. However, you could jump into the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8874/freelancing) and see if anyone else has ideas on how your question could work, if you're having doubts about it.